# Java Play Mustache NPE Error

Tags: java, playback, mustache

We are getting a mustache play error in production (amazon linux EC2 AMI) but not in development (MACs) and we have tried upgrading the jvm, using the jdk instead, and changing from a tomcat deploy model to match our development environments as much as possible but nothing is working.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.  We have lots of shared code in java and javascript using mustache and it would be a big deal to rewrite everything if we had to ditch mustache on the java side.

20:48:52,403 ERROR ~

```
@6al2dd0po
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /mystuff/people

Execution exception (In {module:mustache-0.2}/app/play/modules/mustache/MustacheTags.java around line 32)
NullPointerException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:90)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
    at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:660)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:640)
    at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:695)
    at controllers.MyStuff.people(MyStuff.java:183)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.modules.mustache.MustacheTags._template(MustacheTags.java:32)
    at play.modules.mustache.MustacheTags$_template.call(Unknown Source)
    at /app/views/User/people.html.(line:22)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Can you post the related code? My guess is your template isn't loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the issue is with the threadlocal. In Prod as per my logs, the session gets initialized with the main thread.

```
     [2012-06-30 18:35:38,102] INFO 10097[**main**] - Mustache module initialized
```

However, MustacheTag tries to access with various thread like this during request.

```
     [2012-06-30 17:48:44,669] INFO 66048[**play-thread-1**] - [{module:mustache-0.2}/app/play/modules/mustache/MustacheTags.java:46] _meta() :: MustachePlugin.session():null
```

So I changed the implementation of MustachePlugin like this.Changed line commented out:

```
    //private static ThreadLocal<MustacheSession> session_ = new ThreadLocal<MustacheSession>();
    private static MustacheSession _session = null;
    public static MustacheSession session(){
    //return session_.get();
    return _session;
    }
    public void onConfigurationRead(){
    // some code
    _session = new MustacheSession(compiler, root);
    // some code
    }
```

And it is working fine now in prod mode! I see no reason why it should have been in a ThreadLocal in the first place as the session gets initialized at startup!

Comment: thx This looks promising.  I'm editing the MustachePlugin.java file to try this out but my changes to the java files don't seem to be taking effect.  How do I compile the module again with my changes so play picks them up after a restart?

Comment: Just update the class files in the modules/mustache-0.2/lib/play-mustache.jar directly to test your changes!

Comment: Okay i ran the ant build for the module and it updated the lib.  Looks good CodeTripper!  I'll post the results on the issue in mustache plugin github also.

Comment: Here is the link to the issue in case people are interested: https://github.com/murz/play-mustache/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

your issue is difficult to reproduce so i'll give few pointers here. you have tried to eliminate of issue being env issue. so other possible issues could be

1. data issue: many times reason for production issue is usually difference in actual data  and test data.  check if its data issue which is casuing NPE.
2. code issue: Is there something at `people.html.(line:22)` causing issue. first try removing / altering that to check if thats causing issue. Or can you get source code of `mustache` (exact version which you are using) and see what object its trying to create and where its failing.
3. Properties file for different environments: do you have different proprties file for each env? If yes, have u missed on any property for prod env?

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException on MustacheTags.java at line 32.

This means that you are probably calling a method of the Mustache library and passing a null value.
Try logging all the parameters you transfer to this method (MyStuff.java line 183?).

You can look at the source code of MustacheTags [here](https://github.com/murz/play-mustache/blob/e5df76e6935db4d19aa67f6ab9f18d20efd723a0/app/net/murz/play/mustache/MustacheTags.java), it might help you understand what values you are passing and what should be passed.